# MySQL Query WHERE through multiple pivot tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
products 
+----+--------+
| id | title  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Apple  |
|  2 | Pear   |
|  3 | Banana |
|  4 | Tomato |
+----+--------+

product_variants
+----+------------+------------+
| id | product_id | is_default |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |          1 |          0 |
|  2 |          1 |          1 |
|  3 |          2 |          1 |
|  4 |          3 |          1 |
|  5 |          4 |          1 |
+----+------------+------------+

properties
+----+-----------------+-----------+
| id | property_key_id |   value   |
+----+-----------------+-----------+
|  1 |               1 | Yellow    |
|  2 |               1 | Green     |
|  3 |               1 | Red       |
|  4 |               2 | Fruit     |
|  5 |               2 | Vegetable |
|  6 |               1 | Blue      |
+----+-----------------+-----------+

property_keys
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Color |
|  2 | Type  |
+----+-------+

product_has_properties
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | product_id | property_id |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 |          1 |           4 |
|  2 |          1 |           3 |
|  3 |          2 |           4 |
|  4 |          3 |           4 |
|  5 |          3 |           4 |
|  6 |          4 |           4 |
|  7 |          4 |           5 |
+----+------------+-------------+

product_variant_has_properties
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | variant_id | property_id |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 |          1 |           2 |
|  2 |          1 |           3 |
|  3 |          2 |           6 |
|  4 |          3 |           4 |
|  5 |          4 |           1 |
|  6 |          5 |           1 |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

I need to query my DB so it selects `products` which have certain `properties` attached to the product itself **OR** have those properties attached to one of its related `product_variants`. Also should `properties` with the same properties.property_key_id be grouped like this: `(pkey1='red' OR pkey1='blue') AND (pkey2='fruit' OR pkey2='vegetable')`

Example cases:

- Select all products with `(color='red' AND type='vegetable')`. This should return only Tomato.
- Select all products with `((color='red' OR color='yellow') AND type='fruit')` should return Apple and Banana

Please note that in the example cases above I don't really need to query by properties.value, I can query by properties.id.

I played around a lot with MySQL query's but the biggest problem I'm struggling with is the properties being loaded through two pivot tables. Loading them is no problem but loading them and combining them with the correct `WHERE`, `AND` and `OR` statements is.

Comment: And what you have tried only bounty offer ?

Comment: Could you tell us a bit more about the product variants?

Comment: Based on your sample data -- isn't the tomato yellow, not red?

Comment: Yes, one of the cons of using EAV is exactly this, it becomes nigh impossible to quickly write SELECT queries.  Best of luck!

Comment: From what I can tell you have a Tomato listed as a Fruit and Vegetable but no colour. What are the joins on these tables?

Comment: Considering the tables relate by the columns which it looks like they relate (I'm with @ChristianBarron here), for `Tomato` you have on the `product_has_properties` that it is a `Red (3)` `Fruit (4)`, but if you look at the variants, over the `product_variant_has_properties`, the `Tomato variant 1` has the same `Red (3)` and also `Green (2)` and `Tomato variant 2` has `Blue (6)`. How do you get the result `Tomato` related with `Vegetable`? This is quite confusing to really understand what is intended. Is this the schema you want? Also is the referred pivot part to be addressed?No data about it

Comment: Oh, the *joys* of the Entity-Attribute-Value model. The difficulty that you are experiencing with SQL returning the results you want is due to the mismatch between how SQL works, and the EAV model that's implemented the "attributes" of an entity as rows in a table. **Is there a question being asked here**? Or were you just giving a status report?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code should give you what you're looking for, however you should note that your table currently has a Tomato listed as yellow and a vegetable. Obviously you want the Tomato as red and a Tomato is actually a fruit not a vegetable:

```
Select distinct title 
from products p
inner join
product_variants pv on pv.product_id = p.id
inner join
product_variant_has_properties pvp on pvp.variant_id = pv.id
inner join
product_has_properties php on php.product_id = p.id
inner join
properties ps1 on ps1.id = pvp.property_id --Color
inner join
properties ps2 on ps2.id = php.property_id --Type
inner join
property_keys pk on pk.id = ps1.property_key_id or pk.id = ps2.property_key_id

where ps1.value = 'Red' and ps2.value = 'Vegetable'
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/309ad/3/0

Comment: This query from the EAV model produces a result equivalent to a *trivial* query from the traditional relational model. `SELECT title FROM products p WHERE p.color = 'red' and p.type = 'Vegetable`.  As an exercise, consider the SQL statement that would be required to produce a result that is not as trivial, such as "customers that had more than one order in the past 90 days which included a product that was both 'red' and a 'vegetable'".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used your answer in my application partially, however I slightly altered my DB design to reduce the size of my queries. I now have a new table containing `product_id`, `variant_id`, `property_key_id` and `property_id`. This way I can query my 'property_key_id` and `property_id`s directly on that new table and only have to join `products` and `product_variants` to get the relevant products and variants.

Answer (score 3):

This is a convoluted answer, and it may be possible to do it in a far simpler way. However given that you seem to want to be able to query by `color = xx` and `type = xx`, we clearly need to have columns with those names, which as you've intimated, means we need to pivot the data.

Furthermore, since we want to get all the combinations of colours and types for each product, we need to perform a sort of cross join, to combine them.

This leads us to the query - first we get all the types for a product and its variants, then we join that to all the colours for a product and its variant.  We use `union` to combine the product and variant properties in order to keep them all in the same column, rather than having multiple columns to check.

Of course all products may not have this information specified, so we use `left joins` all the way through. If it is guaranteed that a product will always have at least one colour, and at least one type - they can all be changed to `inner joins`.

Also, in your example you say `tomato` should have a colour of `red`, yet in the sample data you provide i'm sure the `tomato` has a colour of `yellow`.

Anyway, here's the query:

```
select distinct title from 
(select q1.title, q1.value as color, q2.value as type from
(
select products.id, products.title, properties.value, properties.property_key_id
  from products
    left join product_has_properties
      on products.id = product_has_properties.product_id 
    left join properties
      on properties.id = product_has_properties.property_id and properties.property_key_id = 1
union
select product_variants.product_id, products.title, properties.value, properties.property_key_id
  from product_variants
    inner join products
      on product_variants.product_id = products.id
    left join product_variant_has_properties
      on product_variants.id = product_variant_has_properties.variant_id
    left join properties
      on properties.id = product_variant_has_properties.property_id and properties.property_key_id = 1
) q1
left join
(
select products.id,  products.title, properties.value, properties.property_key_id
  from products
    left join product_has_properties
      on products.id = product_has_properties.product_id
    left join properties
      on properties.id = product_has_properties.property_id  and properties.property_key_id = 2
union
select product_variants.product_id, products.title, properties.value, properties.property_key_id
  from product_variants
    inner join products
      on product_variants.product_id = products.id
    left join product_variant_has_properties
      on product_variants.id = product_variant_has_properties.variant_id
    left join properties
      on properties.id = product_variant_has_properties.property_id  and properties.property_key_id = 2
) q2
on q1.id = q2.id 
where q1.value is not null or q2.value is not null
) main
where ((color = 'red' or color = 'yellow') and type = 'fruit')
```

And here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3ded/76

If you were to get more types of property, in addition to colour and type, the query would need to be modified - sorry but that's pretty much what you're stuck with, trying to pivot in mysql

Comment: As the query in this answer demonstrates, what would be relatively simple query in the relational model  e.g. `FROM p WHERE p.color IN ('red','yellow') AND p.type = 'fruit'` is an order of magnitude more complicated to achieve in an EAV model. And that's just a trivial query. Consider a query of a traditional relational model that returns "customers that had two or more orders that included a product that was 'red' or 'yellow' in the past 30 days". The SQL required to replicate that result (in a single SQL statement) from an EAV model is *atrociously* complicated.

Comment: Happily I never claimed this was elegant, nor conducive to scaling. Merely one way of accomplishing a search using the criteria exactly as specified in the question.

Comment: I applaud your effort. I haven't reviewed the SQL statement in your answer to determine if it satisfies the specification; I've assumed  that it does. Based on my own experience, the query in your answer is of the order we expect would be required. (A quick perusal got me a count of 14 table references and 2 derived tables.) My comment was addressed to future readers who come across this answer, looking for "how to" achieve this result. My comment really addresses a wider question... "is a single SQL statement the best way to accomplish this kind of result" from the EAV model.

Comment: Oh, I agree with the sentiment, this answer was more of a thought exercise than anything. It's a bit of a twist on the 'we spend so much time wondering if we could, that we didnt stop to to think if we should' maxim

Answer (score 2):

I think that you make unnecessary complications for your data model, your code and your queries.
Those eventually will be a performance killer for your application.

Your best solution is to consider an easier approach.
Try to flatten your data structure so you will not have such dependencies.

I don't know what exactly product_variants mean so I can't tell exactly how to do the change.

But the main idea is to save the properties always for each variant. 
When you have only 1 variant - define it as a variant too.

And I suggest you to make the properties table to reference the exact variant instead of having global numbering with referencing tables in the structure of:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
| id | property_key_id |   variant_id|   value   |
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 |               1 |           1 | Yellow    |
|  2 |               1 |           1 | Green     |
|  3 |               1 |           1 | Red       |
|  4 |               2 |           1 | Fruit     |
|  5 |               2 |           2 | Vegetable |
|  6 |               1 |           2 | Blue      |
|  7 |               1 |           2 | Yellow    |
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----------+
```

If this approach - you will have duplicate values, but all your queries will be simpler and you will have the freedom to save the values that you want for each specific product variant.

UPDATE

If you have no option to change the structure of the data, "LEFT OUTER JOIN" is your only hope.

Check the below query that selects the ones with color 'Yellow'

```
    select p.* from products p 
       left outer join product_has_properties pp 
            on p.id=pp.product_id 
       left outer join product_variants v 
            on p.id=v.product_id 
       left outer join product_variant_has_properties vp 
            on v.id = vp.variant_id 
    where vp.property_id=1 or pp.property_id=1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I need this structure. Product variants should inherit its product's properties. Products contain properties relevant to the whole product model e.g. CarX, product variants contain properties specific for the product version which may differ by color for example. The property values being stored inside a different table is no issue as I can already query directly by id. I don't need to lookup the `property_id` in the same query.

Comment: @Boyd - review the update that I have added. Let me know if this helps to solve your case.

Answer (score 2):

Considering products and not variants, you can simulate this (at least to some extent) with joins so that you

- substitute each `OR` in your query with an equivalent condition in the `WHERE` clause. E.g. to have `(color='red' OR color='yellow')`,

  ```
  SELECT product_id FROM product_has_properties
  WHERE property_id IN (1, 3)
  ```
- substitute each `AND` in your query with a self-join and a condition in the `WHERE` clause. This should yield rows that correspond to products that have the pair of properties in question. E.g.to have `(color='red' AND type='vegetable')`,

  ```
  SELECT p1.product_id
  FROM product_has_properties p1
  INNER JOIN product_has_properties p2 ON (p1.product_id = p2.product_id)
  WHERE p1.property_id = 3 AND p2.property_id = 5
  ```

Obviously this gets complicated as the number of conditions grows. To get `((color='red' OR color='yellow') AND type='fruit')`, you would need to do

```
SELECT p1.product_id
FROM product_has_properties p1
INNER JOIN product_has_properties p2 ON (p1.product_id = p2.product_id)
WHERE (p1.property_id = 1 OR p1.property_id = 3) AND p2.property_id = 4
```

Assuming that some fruit could be both blue and red, to get `pkey1='red' AND pkey1='blue' AND pkey2='fruit'`, you'd have to do

```
SELECT p1.product_id
FROM product_has_properties p1
INNER JOIN product_has_properties p2 ON (p1.product_id = p2.product_id)
INNER JOIN product_has_properties p3 ON (p1.product_id = p3.product_id)
WHERE p1.property_id = 3 AND p2.property_id = 6 AND p3.property_id = 4
```

There might be some case which isn't covered by this approach, though.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

I'm going to throw out a bit of a different answer to the ones you've been getting. While it is very possible to have a purely SQL answer to this, the question I would pose to you is: Why?

That answer will determine your next step.

If your answer is to try to learn the pure SQL way to do it, there are some great answers here which get you most if not all of the way there.

If your answer is to create scalable dynamic queries for an end application, then you may find your job eased by leaning on your programming language.

## A little personal background

I had a requirement to pivot data with more tables. I was determined I'd try to do this the best possible way, and I spent a lot of time working out what was best for my application. Knowing full well this may not be the same experience you have, I will share my experience here in case it helps you.

I tried to create pure SQL solutions, which did work for specific use cases but required extensive tweaking for each additional use case. When I tried to scale the queries up I first attempted to create Stored Procedures. That was a nightmare and pretty early on in my development I realized it would be a headache to maintain.

I went on to use PHP and create my own query generating. While some of this code has morphed into something that is quite useful for me today, I learned that much of it was going to be challenging to maintain unless I created service libraries. At that point, I realized I was basically going to be creating an Object-relational Mapper (ORM). Unless my application was ***SO*** special and ***SO*** unique that no ORM on the market could come close to doing what I wanted, then I needed to take that opportunity to explore employing an ORM for my application. Despite my initial reservations which caused me to do everything BUT look at an ORM, I have started using one and it helped my development speed increase significantly.

## Reaching your desired end result

```
Select all products with (color='red' AND type='vegetable'). This should return only Tomato.
Select all products with ((color='red' OR color='yellow') AND type='fruit') should return Apple and Banana
```

This is possible in an ORM. What you're describing is only loosely defined in your SQL but is in fact perfectly summarized in OOP. This is what it would look like in PHP, just as an example.

```
<?
Abtract class AbstractProductType {
    public function __construct() {

    }
}

class Color extends AbstractProductType {

}

class Yellow extends Color {

}

class Red extends Color {

}

class Type extends AbstractProductType {

}

class Vegetable extends Type {

}

class Fruit extends Type {

}

class Product {
     public function setColor(Color $color) {
         //
     }
     public function setType(Type $type) {
         //
     }
}

$product = new Product();
$product->setColor(new Red());
$product->setType(new Fruit());
$result = $product->find();
?>
```

The idea behind this is that you can make full use of SQL in object oriented programming.

A slightly lower-key version of this would be to create a class which generates SQL snippets. My personal experience was that that's a lot of work for a limited payback. If your project is going to remain relatively small, it may work out just fine. However, if you antiicpate that your project will grow, then an ORM may well be worth exploring.

## Conclusion

Although I am not sure what language you will be utilizing to query and manipulate your data, there are great ORMs out there which should not be discounted. Despite their many cons (you can find a lot of debate about this all over the internet), I am a reluctant believer that, although certainly not ideal for all situations, they should be considered for some. If this is not one of those situations for you, be prepared to write lots of `JOIN`s yourself. When referencing a table `n` times and requiring a reference back to the table, the only method I am aware of to add a reference is to create `n` `JOIN`s.

I'll be very interested to see if there is a better way, of course!

Comment: Nice answer. But **what was the question?**

Comment: Saw your post. Great answer

Comment: That's what I was referring to when I responded to you. I upvoted it. Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Conditional Aggregation**

You can use conditional aggregation in your `having` clause to see if a product has specific properties. For example, to query all products that have both the "type vegetable" and "color red" properties.

You have to group by both the product id and the product variant id in order to make sure that all the properties you're searching for exist on the same variant or the product itself.

```
select p.id, pv.id from products p
left join product_has_properties php on php.product_id = p.id
left join properties pr on pr.id = php.property_id
left join property_keys pk on pk.id = pr.property_key_id
left join product_variants pv on pv.product_id = p.id
left join product_variant_has_properties pvhp on pvhp.variant_id = pv.id
left join properties pr2 on pr2.id = pvhp.property_id
left join property_keys pk2 on pk2.id = pr2.property_id
group by p.id, pv.id
having (
  count(case when pk.value = 'Color' and pr.value = 'Red' then 1 end) > 0
  and count(case when pk.value = 'Type' and pr.value = 'Vegetable' then 1 end) > 0
) or (
  count(case when pk2.value = 'Color' and pr2.value = 'Red' then 1 end) > 0
  and count(case when pk2.value = 'Type' and pr2.value = 'Vegetable' then 1 end) > 0
)
```

Answer (score 2):

**What was the question?** (I read through the post several times, and I'm still failing to see any actual *question* that is being asked.) A lot of the answers here seem to be answering the question "What SQL statement would return a result from these tables?"  My answer doesn't provide an example or a "how to" guide to writing SQL. My answer addresses a fundamentally different question.

The difficulty that OP is experiencing writing SQL against the tables shown in the "question" is due to (what I refer to as) the "impedance mismatch" between the "Relational" model and the "Entity-Attribute-Value" (EAV) model.

SQL is designed to work with the "Relational" model. Each instance of an entity is represented as a tuple, stored a row in table. The attributes of an entity are stored as values in columns of the entity row.

The EAV model differs significantly from the Relational model. It moves attribute values off of the entity row, and moves them into multiple, separate  rows in other tables. And that makes writing queries more complicated, if the queries are attempting to emulate queries against a "Relational" model by transforming the data from the "EAV" representation back into a "Relational" representation.

There's a couple of approaches to writing SQL queries against the EAV model that emulate the results returned from a Relational model (as demonstrated by the example SQL provided in other answers to this "question".

One approach is to use *subqueries* in the `SELECT` list to return values of attributes as columns in the entity row.

Another approach is to perform joins between the row in the entity table to the rows in the attribute table(s), and use a `GROUP BY` to collapse the rows, and in the `SELECT` list, use conditional expressions "pick out" the value to be returned for a column.

There's lots of examples of both of those approaches. And neither is really better than the other, the suitability of each approach really depends on the particular use case.

---

While it is possible to write SQL queries against the EAV-style tables shown, those queries are an order of magnitude *more complicated* than equivalent  queries against data stored in a "relational" model.

A result returned by a trivial query in the relational model, e.g.

```
SELECT p.id
  FROM product p
 WHERE p.color = 'red'
```

To return that same set from data in the EAV model requires a much more complex SQL query, involving joins of several tables and/or subqueries.

And once we move beyond the trivial query, to a query where we want to return attributes from multiple related entities... as a simple example, return information about orders in the past 30 days for products that were 'red'

```
SELECT c.customer_name
     , c.address
     , o.order_date
     , p.product_name
     , l.qty
  FROM customer c
  JOIN order o ON ...
  JOIN line_item l ON ...
  JOIN product p ON ...
 WHERE p.color = 'red'
   AND o.order_date >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 30
```

getting that same result, using SQL, from the EAV model is *way* more convoluted and confusing, and can be an excruciating exercise in frustration.

Certainly, it's possible to write the SQL. And once we do manage to get SQL statements that work to return a "correct" resultset, when the number of rows in the tables scale up beyond the trivial demonstration, up to the kind of volumes we expect databases to handle... the performance of those queries is horrendous (as compared to queries returning the same results from a traditional Relational model).

(And we've not even touched on the additional complexity for just adding and updating the attributes of entities, enforcing referential integrity between entities, etc.)

But **why** would we want to do that? **Why** do we need (or want) to write SQL statements against the EAV model tables that emulate the results returned from queries against Relational model tables?.

---

Bottom line, if we are going to use an EAV model, we are much better off *not* attempting to use a single SQL statement to return results like we'd get back from a query of a "Relational" model.

The problem of retrieving information from the EAV model is much more suited to a programming language that is object-oriented, and provides a framework. Something that is entirely lacing in SQL.